# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent in node js MVC approach

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am getting the following error ...

```
   events.js:160
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
     ^
 Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
      at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
      at ServerResponse.header 
      (C:\level3proj\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:730:10)
```

.. when I execute the following code

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var express = require('express');

    // express router used to define routes
    var userRouter= express.Router();

    var userModel = mongoose.model('User');
    var allUsers = [];
    var fs = require('fs');

    module.exports.controller = function(app) {
      userRouter.get('/all',function(req,res) {
        res.send("this is a route to get information on particular ");
        userModel.find({},function(err,allUsers) {
          if(err) {
            res.send(err);
          } else {
            res.send(allUsers);
          }
        }); // end user model
      }); // end get all users
      app.use('/users', userRouter);
    } // end controller code
```

When I load

http://localhost:3000/users/all

the result is presented and at the same it is throwing error in the console.

Why I am getting an error on console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send the responce 2 times. The first one is here

```
 res.send("this is a route to get information on particular ");
```

And after that here

```
if(err) {
    res.send(err);
} else {
    res.send(allUsers);
}
```

Remove the first sending and your responce will work

Answer (score 0):

You can't send http [response](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) twice.

You already send it with:

```
res.send("this is a route to get information on particular ");
```

You can't then make a database query and send a response again.

Comment: So what is the way to send response two or more time if i have more then one routes in my user.js file